# Dynamic array of structures C++

Tags: c++, arrays, function, dynamic, structure

I'm required to create a dynamic phone list using C++

So, the way I would go about this was to create a simple 1D dynamic array of structures where each structure carries a name and phone number.

```
struct Person {
char Name[100];
char Phone_Number[100];};
```

Now I'm not sure how to go about creating a function that adds a new entry to the list by creating a new structure and adding it.
Something along the lines of

```
void add () {
Person person1;
cout << "Please enter name:" << endl;
cin.getline(person1.Name, 100, '\n');
cout << "Please enter number:" << endl;
cin.getline(person1.Phone_Number, 100, '\n');
cout << "Successful!" << endl;}
```

??

Comment: Please read about `std::vector` and `std::string`.

Comment: C++ was invented so that you don't have to deal with problems like this. Start using `std:string`, `std:vector` and all the other powerful tools that object oriented programming enable.

Comment: This sounds like homework. Are you required to use raw arrays?

Comment: I advise you to do it with `int` before you attempt it with `Person`.

Comment: If you wish to produce dynamic manner, use string to replace primitive data type (char). Later on, vectorized the person class, as vector<Person> People. "People" is a set of multiple objects.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use pointers to create a dynamic array of a struct. If you want more technical information about pointers, you can check [this page](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&ved=2ahUKEwiRj5nTtcrmAhXEmq0KHeW4DOEQFjAEegQIBBAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cplusplus.com%2Fdoc%2Ftutorial%2Fpointers%2F&usg=AOvVaw2lBzgVAmoqeR9jrej0l2xj).

To declare your dynamic array you just need to declare:

```cpp
int n = 10;
Person* persons = new Person[n];
```

`n` will be your total number of persons, and `persons` will be your dynamic array. You can access to members in the same way as normal arrays.

```cpp
cout<<persons[5].Name<<endl;
```

Now, to add a new member of your array you need to increase the total number of persons, create a new instance of your Person array with the new size, and then copy the values of the old array into the new one.

```cpp
void increaseArraySize(int n, Person* persons){
    Person* temp = new Person[n];

    for(int i=0; i < n; i++){
        temp[i] = persons[i];
    }

    persons = new Person[n+1];

    for(int i=0; i < n+1; i++){
        persons[i] = temp[i];
    }

    delete[] temp;
}

void add(int &n, Person* persons){
    Person person1;
    cout << "Please enter name:" << endl;
    cin.getline(person1.Name, 100, '\n');
    cout << "Please enter number:" << endl;
    cin.getline(person1.Phone_Number, 100, '\n');
    cout << "Successful!" << endl;

    increaseArraySize(n, persons);
    persons[n] = person1;
    persons[n] = person1;
    n++;
}

void print(int n, Person* persons){
    for(int i=0; i < n; i++){
        cout<<persons[i].Name<<endl;
        cout<<persons[i].Phone_Number<<endl;
        cout<<endl;
    }
}

int main(){
    int n = 0;
    Person* persons = new Person[n];

    add(n, persons);
    add(n, persons);

    print(n, persons);

    delete[] persons;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you intent to change a pointer's value in a function, you have to pass it's pointer as parameter. Meaning, a double pointer. Like Person** persons. Also creating temp is completely unnecessary, and you're not freeing the original `persons` before overwriting it with the new array, so there's a memory leak.

Comment: Please do not use plain C-style arrays in C++. And try to avoid to use ````new```` in C++. And never use raw pointers for owned memory. Then you will find the solution automatically.